# What does the drowning sequence represent?

Tags: analysis, a-single-man

In "A Single Man", directed by Tom Ford, and based on eponymous novel by Christopher Isherwood, there is a reoccurring scene that features the protagonist, George, naked, underwater, apparently struggling not to drown.

Here's an example, from the end of the film:

What does the scene mean? What is the symbolism in it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a metaphor of drowning in grief:

> The hero of the story, adapted from the novel by Christopher
>   Isherwood, explains himself in voice-overs: “Just get through the
>   goddamned day: bit melodramatic, perhaps, but then again, my heart has
>   been broken. Feel as if I’m drowning, sinking, can’t breathe,” he
>   says.

([source](http://www.newyorker.com/magazine/2009/12/21/free-and-uneasy))

He drowns alone and in silence:

> The theme of silence which resonates subtly throughout A Single Man,
>   of course, is also a reminder of the real tragedy of George’s loss:
>   that his grief has been censored by a society which demands his
>   invisibility.  He is not allowed the benefit of condolence and ritual
>   by participating in Jim’s funeral; he is excluded and denied the
>   status of an official “family member.”  His last sixteen years with
>   his partner have been omitted from the record.  Through this erasure
>   by uncontrollable external forces, as demonstrated by the repeated
>   metaphor of a man quietly drowning in the ocean, the film suggests,
>   especially in George’s final moments, that suffering is most extreme
>   when experienced in silence.

([source](http://theliteraryunderground.org/flatmancrooked/?p=6105))

It also leads to irony when he's actually drowning:

> The swimming motive is actually what starts the movie. Drowning to be
>   exact. As if George was drowning without love, without Jim, without
>   something that made his life right, important, valuable. He daydreams
>   about it during his lecture as if he wanted to drown completely,
>   disappear. It is ironic, and it is not the first irony in the film,
>   that after he will actually be drowning during the swim with Kenny, he
>   will realize how valuable life itself, moments we have are.

([source](http://whatthemovie.com/review/469))